# How can i redirect the invalid form submissions back to the form without losing the errors?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm using RefineryCMS, and so all the pages are stored in the database. The only view in sight is a show.html.erb, which is responsible for rendering all the pages on the site. That makes it hard to build forms and form validations.

I'm wondering how I could program the controller to redirect back to a form page and still keep the errors object necessary for form validations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps storm it temporarily in the memory? a file? a table? a... I'm out of ideas. (Sorry, I don't really know what RefineryCMS is, but I'd do that in my rails app. Just store it in a variable for the next request)